# How to capture the last returned value from sql session in the unix script?

Tags: unix, oracle-apps, oracle-application-server

I am calling a procedure  from  shell script , my procedure has an out parameter which will return '2' at last in case of any error . My question is how do i capture this last returned value/row in the unix environment ? . i need to terminate my host program with exit 1 based on the return value "2".
Any suggestions will helpful .

Answer (score 0):

You could directly assign the output value to a shell variable.

Or, alternarively, you can call the PL/SQL procedure in SQL*Plus and store the OUTPUT parameter's value in a local file. And then in your shell script, `grep` the required value from the file.

For example,

```
out_variable=`sqlplus -s $conn_string <<EOF
SET SERVEROUTPUT ON SIZE 1000000
SET FEEDBACK OFF
whenever sqlerror exit 1;
variable o_val number;

EXEC myproc(:o_val);
EOF`
```

So, the `out_variable` will have the output value of the procedure. Using backticks, will execute and assign the output from sqlplus to the shell variable.

Comment: This is the same way i am doing , But the problem is my procedure will return hell lot of DBMS output statements  after the `echo $out_variable` And finally returns the  return code in my log , can you please  help me with the syntax how to grep the o_val from $out_variable .